# Cannot find module DOCKER RUN

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to run a simple docker image with a index.js file in my /build folder with a simple console.log('Hello world')

My docker file is:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /test/build
COPY ./ ./
CMD node index.js
```

I create the image in my directory with:

```
docker build -t hello-docker .
```

Then I run:

```
docker run hello-docker
```

But I keep on getting the error:

```
cannot find module /test/build/index.js
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you running `docker build` from the folder that contains `index.js`?

Comment: Not, I am running it from the root of the directory of the project but I have tried it to run it from /build as well and it doesn't work either

Comment: so the `index.js` will end up in `./build/index.js`, meaning you should run `node ./build/index.js`.

Comment: So the dock file would be:

FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /test/build
COPY ./ ./
CMD node ./build/index.js

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capturing my comment as an answer for posterity - since the `docker build` command will be run from the application's root, the `index` file will end up under the `build` directory. I.e., the application should be run using:

```
CMD node ./build/index.js
```